# Routing fails when api is created as a web application under another site

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I developed a rest api using ASP.net web api. When I deploy this rest api on iis, I need to create it as a web application under an asp.net web site. When I was deploying the rest api as a new web site in iis, then things worked fine. I was using the following Route `api/{controller}/{id}`. 
When I created the rest api as a web application underneath asp.net web site project, I named the web application as api. I can't access the api methods now. Can someone point what I do wrong?

Comment: What happens when you try: api/api/{controller}/{id}?

Comment: What version of web api? Is it a web application (in the Default Web Site sub-tree)? Do you have a route debugger installed in the project (displays registered routes)? Is this local IIS?

Answer (score 2):

WebApi is based on global.asax and web.config configurations and you can't have 2 of these files inside in the same application. In the scenario you described, it sounds like you need to create a "Virtual Directory" in IIS for the second application instead of making just a "Sub Folder".

The Virtual Directory will allow you to declare a new web.config and global.asax where you set the new routings and configurations method for your second application.

For a full walkthrough on how you can perform this please refer to this site:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb763173(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I had it working now by removing the api from the route. Thanks for the answer though. It's useful.

Comment: What about the web.config files? When I create a virtual directory, then does rest api web config still inherit from the upper level web.config which belongs to my asp.net web site?

Comment: @neo no if you have a virtual directory you will need to copy over your configurations if they are the same.

Comment: What if I want to keep two applications' config files separate? Virtual Directory supports that scenario?

Comment: well that is one of the things virtual directory does their config files are totally separate(independent) one from another.

Comment: When I created virtual directory called api, then I am not able to access the api. I get an error that says "It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS."